# Extraccion de texto PDF no obtengo nada

Tags: python-2.7, pdf

Lo que deseo hacer es extraer un texto de un archivo pdf, el problema es que obtengo solo espacios en blanco, esto ocurre solo con este archivo.
el codigo es el siguiente:
(no es largo)

---

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import PyPDF2

pdfName = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/Documents",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("pdf files","*.pdf"),("all files","*.*")))

pdfFileObj = open(pdfName, 'rb')
pdfReaderObj = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
print(pdfReaderObj.numPages)
pageObj = pdfReaderObj.getPage(0)
page_content = pageObj.extractText()
print (page_content.encode('utf-8'))
file = open('pdfText.txt','a+')
file.write(page_content.encode('utf-8'))
file.close()

pdfFileObj.close()
```

---

el output de este codigo deberia de ser ...

- [un print con la cantidad de paginas del documento]
- [contenido de la primer pagina del documento pdf]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La propia [documentación del método `extracText()`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PageObject.html#PyPDF2.pdf.PageObject.extractText) avisa que no es muy fiable y que puede fallar en muchos PDFs.

Alternativas:

- Si estás en una máquina unix, instala `pdftotext` (en Ubuntu sería el paquete `poppler-utils`. He probado que sobre el fichero que indicas es capaz de extraer el texto. Por ejemplo:

  ```
  $ pdftotext -f1 -l1 Tufichero.pdf
  $ cat Tufichero.txt
  MIRA DROR - Listado de Precios Profesionales CABA y GBA - Agosto 2019
  limpieza facial

  150g

  250g

  500g

  Emulsión de Limpieza profunda.

  $ 220

  $ 330

  [...etc...]
  ```

  Naturalmente puedes ejecutar este comando también desde un script python si fuera necesario (con `os.system()` o con `subprocess.run()`).
- Similar a la anterior, pero usa `pdftohtml`. Esto, como cabe esperar, genera un HTML. En el caso de este fichero en particular, el HTML no es muy útil, pues una serie de líneas iguales a las que extrajo `pdftotext`, pero separadas entre sí por el tag `<br/>` en vez de retornos de carro. En otros ficheros, en cambio, `pdftohtml` puede generar un marcado mejor, que refleje la estructura del documento y que haga más sencillo analizarlo posteriormente con BeautifulSoup o con lxml.
- Si no quieres instalar nada en tu máquina, puedes usar la biblioteca [`tika` para Python](https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python), pero cuidado, esta biblioteca no es más que un cliente HTTP que conecta con el servidor [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) que es quien hace verdaderamente el trabajo. Si manejas datos privados, quizás no debas usar un servidor externo para procesarlos. En todo caso, la interfaz que te da la biblioteca python es extremadamente simple. No te permite especificar qué página extraer, sino que te da directamente todo el texto del documento. Por ejemplo:

  ```
  from tika import parser

  pdfName = "Tufichero.pdf"
  raw = parser.from_file(pdfName)
  txt = raw["content"].strip()  # Quitamos los retornos de carro que tiene
                                # al inicio y al final
  print(txt[:100])              # Mostrar sólo los 100 primeros caracteres
  ```

  y sale algo similar a lo que extraía `pdftotext`, pero quizás mejor organizado de cara a procesarlo, pues parece que "agrupa" el texto por celdas, en vez de por líneas.

  ```
  limpieza facial
  Emulsión de Limpieza profunda.

  150g
  $ 220

  250g
  $ 330

  500g
  $ 592

  limpieza facial
  ```